# Как сделать запись в файл не перезаписывая его полностью?

Tags: java, файлы

Мне нужно чтобы все что было записано в файле до этого сохранилось, при этом добавилась новая строчка. Вот мой код:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataBaseFile));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);

out.println(username + "," + password + "," + balance);
out.close();
```

Он просто удаляет все существовавшие строчки в этом файле и делает одну новую.

Comment: Так и есть, дубликат, достаточно включить `appendMode` при создании `FileWriter`: `new FileWriter(dataBaseFile, true)`